# How do you handle the boundary term when integrating a product of three functions defined over $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f, g: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. I am working on an integral of the form
$$\int_U \big((f \cdot \nabla)f\big) \cdot g dx.$$
Written in components,
$$\sum_{i = 1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \int_U f_i g_j \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} dx.$$
For the sake of notation I will rewrite the above using the summation convention as:
$$\int_U f_i g_j (\partial_j f_i) dx.$$
After integrating by parts I get:
$$\text{boundary terms} -\int_U (\partial_jf_i) g_j  f_i dx -\int_U f_i (\partial_jg_j)  f_i dx.$$

Based on index matching and Green's identity I suspect the boundary term will
$$\int_{\partial U} f_ig_j f_i e_j \cdot \hat{n} dx$$
where $e_j$ is the unit vector in the $j$th direction and $\hat{n}$ is the unit vector normal to the boundary of $U$.

Is this correct? I would like to find a better justification than just index matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, your index is not correct. $(f\cdot\nabla)f$ is a vector whose $j$-th component is $f\cdot\nabla f_j=\sum_i f_i\partial_if_j$, hence using summation convention we have $$\big((f \cdot \nabla)f\big) \cdot g=f_i\partial_if_jg_j=f_ig_j(\partial_if_j)=\partial_i(f_ig_jf_j)-f_j\partial_i(f_ig_j).$$
  Using [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#For_bounded_open_subsets_of_Euclidean_space) we obtain
  $$\int_U \partial_i(f_ig_jf_j)\,dx=\int_{\partial U}f_ig_jf_jn_i\,dS,$$
  where $\vec{n}=(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ is the the unit vector normal to $\partial U$. Therefore,
  \begin{align*}
  \int_U\big((f \cdot \nabla)f\big) \cdot g\,dx&=\int_{\partial U}f_ig_jf_jn_i\,dS-\int_U f_j(\partial_if_i)g_j+f_jf_i\partial_ig_j\,dx\\
  &=\int_{\partial U}(f\cdot\vec n)(f\cdot g)\,dS-\int_U (f\cdot g)\operatorname{div}f\,dx-\int_Uf\cdot\big((f\cdot\nabla)g\big)\,dx.
  \end{align*}
- Another perspective not using index: since $f\cdot\nabla$ is a differential operator, by Leibniz's rule we have
  \begin{align*}
  \big((f \cdot \nabla)f\big) \cdot g&=(f\cdot\nabla)(f\cdot g)-f\cdot\big((f\cdot\nabla)g\big)\\
  &=\operatorname{div}\big((f\cdot g)f\big)-(f\cdot g)\operatorname{div}f-f\cdot\big((f\cdot\nabla)g\big).
  \end{align*}
  Using [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement) we obtain
  $$\int_U \operatorname{div}\big((f\cdot g)f\big)\,dx=\int_{\partial U}(f\cdot g)f\cdot\vec n\,dS=\int_{\partial U}(f\cdot\vec n)(f\cdot g)\,dS.$$
  Therefore,
  $$\int_U\big((f \cdot \nabla)f\big) \cdot g\,dx=\int_{\partial U}(f\cdot\vec n)(f\cdot g)\,dS-\int_U (f\cdot g)\operatorname{div}f\,dx-\int_Uf\cdot\big((f\cdot\nabla)g\big)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am taking the components of $(f \cdot \nabla) f$ to be indexed by $i$, so my $i$ is your $j$. In that case are my indices still incorrect?

Comment: @CBBAM You're welcome. Yes, they are still incorrect. The $i$-th component of $(f\cdot\nabla)f$ is $f\cdot\nabla f_i=f_1\partial_1f_i+f_2\partial_2f_i+f_3\partial_3f_i=f_j\partial_jf_i$. But yours is $f_i\partial_j f_i$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Oh yes I see my mistake now, thanks again!